# All elements video full screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, html5-video, fullscreen

I have this list of videos:

```
<video class="filme" preload="auto" src="public/videos/video.mp4" style="display: none;"></video>
<video class="filme" preload="auto" src="public/videos/video.mp4" style="display: none;"></video>
<video class="filme" preload="auto" src="public/videos/video.mp4" style="display: none;"></video>
```

And when I click in this button:

```
<button id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
```

I would like all videos staying full screen. It is possible?

Comment: huh? all videos full screen at the same time? anyway, you can;t do fullscreen with javascript. best you can do is full size of the browser.

Comment: @Pamblam [You can do fullscreen now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) but you're right. All videos at fullscreen at the same time doesn't make sense.

Comment: is necessary because when one video ends the next start so all need stay full screen.

Comment: kewl! found this link on Mike's link above. it's got the code you need, but still, all videos at once, not sure if that will work. you probably have to wait til the video is done and then fullscreen the next one.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Comment: @Pamblam This is 2016, all major video players on the web have been using the Fullscreen API for a while already ;)

Comment: So, you are loading all the videos into fullscreen so that you can play one after the other? That is not going to work like you want. Just queue, load and fullscreen the next video AFTER the previous one is completed.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - I'm not familiar with a single one. MDN says it's still experimental technology. Most major players on the web use flash for fullscreen, not javascript.

Comment: @Pamblam YouTube, Facebook, Vimeo... every sites have changed to HTML5 players long long ago when Apple says they don't want Flash. "Experimental technology" only means it still needs prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is:

```
var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
var isFull = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

if(isFull == 'FullscreenOn' ){

    var oldVideo = currentVideo-1;

    if ($("video")[oldVideo].exitFullscreen) {
        $("video")[oldVideo].exitFullscreen();
    } else if ($("video")[oldVideo].mozExitFullScreen) {
        $("video")[oldVideo].mozExitFullScreen(); // Firefox
    } else if ($("video")[oldVideo].webkitExitFullscreen) {
        $("video")[oldVideo].webkitExitFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }

    if ($("video")[currentVideo].requestFullscreen) {
        $("video")[currentVideo].requestFullscreen();
    } else if ($("video")[currentVideo].mozRequestFullScreen) {
        $("video")[currentVideo].mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    } else if ($("video")[currentVideo].webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        $("video")[currentVideo].webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }    
}
```